# RemoteWebDriver Chrome - start maximized

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I need chrome to start maximized when running via the selenium grid.

This is how do I initialize it now:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome", "http://www.google.com");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Chrome does come up, but not maximized. In usual ChromeDriver I did it like this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

But I dont know how to pass it to RemoteWebDriver. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

That's how I do it.

Comment: The code above looks good, but when I tried it, I got "cannot parse capability: chromeOptions on the node." Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, sorry. I didn't observe the Webdriver development over the past two years too much. Try looking for a mention of this in the chsngelog, or post a new question.

Comment: I found out the answer to my question here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7043 with new selenium update options is used slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it, so lets answer my own question :)

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome", "http://www.google.com");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

should work :}

Comment: I will accept your answer - to give you appreciation for the effort. Anyways "google before post" should be new "think before speak" - at least in my case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions did not work for me but this did

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = options.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
capabilities?.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");

Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Hope this helps someone.